# How to shutdown akka from java

Tags: java, akka

I have an akka (akka-actor_2.11) application that we use for stress testing one of our systems. The top level actor called RunCoordinatorActor is able to know based on responses coming from its subordinates when the work is finished.

When the work is finished the RunCoordinatorActor makes a call to `getContext().system().shutdown()` and then in the main method there is a loop checking for the `system.isTerminated()` call to return true. All works fine and I am happy with the way it works. However both `system.sutdown()` and `system.isTerminated()` methods are marked as deprecated and I am trying to figure out the right way to implement a graceful shutdown without using them.

Here is my main class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    if (new ArgumentsValidator().validate(args)) {
        // If the arguments are valid then we can load spring application
        // context on here.
        final ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(
                M6ApplicationContext.class);

        // Use an akka system to be able to send messages in parallel
        // without doing the low level thread manipulation ourselves.
        final ActorSystem system = context.getBean(ActorSystem.class);
        final ActorRef runCoordinator = system.actorOf(SPRING_EXT_PROVIDER.get(system)
                .props("RunCoordinatorActor"), "runCoordinator");
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        runCoordinator.tell(new StartTesting(), ActorRef.noSender());

        do {
            LOGGER.info("Waiting for the process to finish");
            Thread.sleep(60000L);
            // What would be the alternative for isTerminated() code below
        } while (!system.isTerminated());
    }
}
```

and here is my call to shutdown inside the RunCoordinator class:

```
@Named("RunCoordinatorActor")
@Scope("prototype")
public class RunCoordinator extends UntypedActor {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Object message) throws Exception {
        ....
        if (message instanceof WorkDone) {
            getContext().system().shutdown();
        }
    }
}
```

I can see there is another method called terminate() that returns a Future and if I replace the shutdown call with that it all works OK too.

```
if (message instanceof WorkDone) {
    Future<Terminated> work = getContext().system().terminate();
    // But where should I put the call work.isCompleted()
    // and how would I make the main aware of it
}
```

I could find some scala examples on here [shutdown-patterns-in-akka-2](http://letitcrash.com/post/30165507578/shutdown-patterns-in-akka-2) but they still use system.shutdown in the end so not sure how up to date that post still is.

Thank you in advance for your inputs.

Comment: So do you have something against the Poison Pill method?

Comment: No. I just don't know where and now to use it to address my problem: a graceful shutdown.

Comment: Well, one thought I have is that if you can refactor to use a work pulling pattern, it's rather easy to check if all actors are done working with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was not that hard to find once I looked closer into the ActorSystem API.

All I had to do was to add this to my RunCoordinator class:

```
if (message instanceof WorkDone) {
    getContext().system().terminate();
}
```

And had a `Future<Terminated> workDone = system.whenTerminated();` defined in my main class which after the change became:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    if (new ArgumentsValidator().validate(args)) {
        // If the arguments are valid then we can load spring application
        // context on here.
        final ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(
                M6ApplicationContext.class);

        // Use an akka system to be able to send messages in parallel
        // without doing the low level thread manipulation ourselves.
        final ActorSystem system = context.getBean(ActorSystem.class);
        final Future<Terminated> workDone = system.whenTerminated();
        final ActorRef runCoordinator = system.actorOf(SPRING_EXT_PROVIDER.get(system)
                .props("RunCoordinatorActor"), "runCoordinator");
        runCoordinator.tell(new StartTesting(), ActorRef.noSender());

        do {
            LOGGER.info("Waiting for the process to finish");
            Thread.sleep(60000L);
        } while (!workDone.isCompleted());
    }
}
```

All worked very well after this. I am still surprised google cold not take me to any existing example showing how to do it.